# C#/MSBuild Compiler deletes output files before Debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a DLL project that produces a report that requires certain js/css/xsl files, each of which is set to "Copy Always" to the output directory.

This DLL is then consumed by an EXE, which in turn copies the report files into its own bin/Debug directory, again correctly.

However - when I debug the EXE, just before it runs, MSBuild seems to do a quick compile, which deletes the report files from the output of the EXE.  The EXE then, inevitably fails.

I can see from Process Monitor that it is the MSBuild process that is deleting the files, but can't fathom out why it is doing this, and then not replacing them!  This is an issue with MSBuild 4.5/Visual Studio 2012.

If you need any information for debugging purposes, please let me know!